# Необычный MySQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!

Требуется немного необычный MySQL запрос.

Суть вот в чём:

У нас есть таблица, допустим, 'table', у неё поля: 'id', 'name', 'tag', 'status'.

Задача: сделать выборку одинаковых 'name' (т.е., допустим, если у нас в БД значения name: 'Иван', 'Александр', 'Александр', 'Иван', то нужно, чтобы БД выдала либо Иван Иван, либо Александр Александр), также нужно сделать условие, чтобы поле 'status' было равно '1'.

Мои наработки:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`table`)
WHERE `name` IN (SELECT `name` FROM `table` GROUP BY `name` HAVING count(*)>1)
AND `status` = '1'
```

Но по этому запросу выдаёт и Ивана, и Александра, а мне же нужно, чтобы выдавало только какое-то одно значение.

Comment: > какое-то одно значение

И вам без разницы какое? Нет никаких критериев отбора?

Comment: Можно по id - какое id первое, то значение и показываться будет. Но, в общем-то, это не важно для меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите [такой вариант](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc5e8/3/0). Только смысла я в этом не нахожу, т.к. в этом случае, всегда будет выбираться одна и та же запись. В примере - это "Александр".

Comment: смысл в том, что после выборки и определённых операций будет меняться status, а значит в следующей выборке уже не попадётся снова то же значение

Comment: @nick777, вам видней.

P.S. Я там чуть подправил пример и ссылку изменил

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленный вариант, но там только одно значение выдаётся, а мне требуется чтобы все выдавались (т.е. и повторяющиеся, т.е. 3 строки 'Александр' должно выдаваться, если брать Вашу таблицу в пример).

Comment: Как объяснили, так и ответил. [Смотрите сейчас](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bca5/3/0)

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось. Правда в PhpMyAdmin сработало только если убрать LIMIT 1.

Comment: Ещё понадобилось чтобы 2 столбца были с одинаковыми значениями. Т.е. 'name' и 'alt_status'. Т.е. если у нас значения: [0] [ 'name' => 'Aleks', 'alt_status' => '2', 'status' => '1' ], [1] [ 'name' => 'Aleks', 'alt_status' => '2', 'status' => '1' ], [2] [ 'name' => 'Vova', 'alt_status' => '1', 'status' => '1' ], [3] [ 'name' => 'Aleks', 'alt_status' => '3', 'status' => '1' ]

То должно выдавать 1-ю и 2-ю строки. Пробовал с помощью EXISTS И IN, также пытался засунуть подзапрос SELECT в FROM, но ничего не получилось. Помогите, пожалуйста.